# jQuery animate example logic doesn't work

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-animate, slide

i have a problem with my test site:

http://devauth.labscope.de/htmlapp/report-overview.html

My problem is this: when I scale the browser window to 768px width, a header appears with two icons (left and right). When I click them the respective menu is toggled with a sliding animation. When I click the right-hand icon a second time nothing happens. Can you tell me why this happens?

Here my jQuery Code:

```
 jQuery('#content, #footer').each(function() {
            $(this).data('left', this.style.left);
        });

        jQuery('.category').on("click", function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            var state   = $(this).data('state'),
                wrapper = $('#content').data('left'),
                footer  = $('#footer').data('left');


            jQuery("#content").animate({
                left: state ? wrapper : 250,
                duration: 1000
            }, "normal");

            jQuery("#footer").animate({
                left: state ? footer : 250,
                duration: 1000
            }, "normal");

            jQuery(this).data('state', !state);
        });

    jQuery('#content, #footer').each(function() {
        $(this).data('right', this.style.right);
    });

    jQuery('.filter').on("click", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var state   = $(this).data('state'),
            wrapper = $('#content').data('right'),
            footer  = $('#footer').data('right');

        jQuery("#content").animate({
            right: state ? wrapper : 250,
            duration: 1000
        }, "normal");

        jQuery("#footer").animate({
            right: state ? footer : 250,
            duration: 1000
        }, "normal");

        jQuery(this).data('state', !state);


    });
```

I hope someone can help me to fix this bug.

Comment: I don't understand a word of what you are saying, I can't see any left/right icons on the header. Can you explain it a bit better please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of animating `Right` by 250, try animating `left` by -250.